# CanCan does not upload images to the server (ckeditor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, monkeypatching, cancancan

When I upload a picture to the server is a request to `Ckeditor::PicturesController#create`(it is located in [gem ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor)) and an error appears:

```
CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed (This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.)
```

how can I not using monkeypatching (not specify `skip_authorization_check` in `Ckeditor::PicturesController`), and solve this problem in **abillity.rb** or or another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to add the following rules in your **ability.rb**, like mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#cancan-integration)?

```
can :access, :ckeditor
can [:read, :create, :destroy], Ckeditor::Picture
```